# ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.contrib.admindocs.middleware: "No module named middleware"

Tags: javascript, python, django, email, webmail

I'm trying to install webpymail (https://code.google.com/p/webpymail/wiki/Installation), I did everything as is said in the tutorial, but upon starting the app I get `A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.` and in server logs
`ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.contrib.admindocs.middleware: "No module named middleware"`

What could be the cause of that and how do I fix it?

Comment: If you have `django.contrib.admindocs.middleware` in your apps list, then remove `.middleware` part or comment out the line

Answer (score 2):

This is a spot where you need to pay close attention to the version of the documentation you're reading.

If you're on Django 1.5 or lower, use:

```
'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
```

If you're on Django 1.6 or greater, use:

```
'django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.XViewMiddleware',
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem a few days ago...

- add `'django.contrib.admindocs,'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`
- add `'django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.XViewMiddleware',` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Django 1.6. This is the line that worked for me in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:

```
django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware
```

The other suggestion for Django 1.6 didn't work for me.